# Blazor - Passing Parameter to the Custom Layout

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

**How to pass parameter to Custom Layout?**

While clicking a `NavLink` the Custom Layout will be rendered inside the '`MainLayout`'.

In '`MainLayout`' we have added a 'Custom Layout' as nested one and we want to pass a parameter to the Custom Layout from `MainLayout`.

**Updated:**

**CustomLayout Page:**

```
@layout MSLayout
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<section id="Content-nested">
    <div>
        @Body
    </div>
</section>
```

Here we want to pass some value from `MSLayout` to `CustomLayout`.

`CustomLayout` will be used in another component:

```
@layout CustomLayout
@page "/NestedComponent"

<h1>This component is in 'Nested layout!!!'</h1>
```